# Best way to make a WPF application that will later become a library for a AutoCAD .net program

Tags: c#, wpf, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm making a .net program for AutoCAD that is using a WPF window as the interface. At the moment I'm designing the WPF window as an application and then changing it to a library that I reference in to the AutoCAD .net program. I'm doing this so I can quickly check how the WPF window is working with out having to start up AutoCAD every time I want to check just the WPF application.

Doing it this way is rather tedious though as I have to repeatedly alter the WPF window project from application to library and this sometimes causes things that I previously had working in the application to no longer work in the library (such as resources).

I'm wondering if there is a better way I could approach this. Ideally I'd like to not have to reference in the WPF window and just have it as part of the AutoCAD .net program in such a way that I can easily launch just the WPF part to check it without having to start AutoCAD too.

Comment: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=1911627&siteID=123112

Comment: And check MVVM pattern to separate view from business (if not too late). If you do so, you will get code that works also without a view and everything is clean, because presentation and business code is not mixed anymore. So extracting the business code is much more simple. Maybe you even can reuse it without any modification. You could then use a wrapper (adapter or decorator) to connect your library code to any Cad plugin context.

Comment: This link just takes me to the autodesk site. Can you please elaborate on what I'm meant to be seeing?

Comment: @BionicCode I've added view models for each of my wpf components so the code is separate from the presentation. I'm wondering how I run just the wpf window if I combine it in the AutoCAD .net program

Comment: Its not clear what you want to accomplish. If you want to leave you wpf application as a library then just create another project application and add yours as a reference. If you need to start it under autocad then I don't see how you could not have to open autocad each time?  what do you mean by "not have to reference in the WPF window"?

Comment: @noone392 I mean have the code for the WPF window as part of the AutoCAD .net program and not as a referenced library but be able to just open the WPF window without starting AutoCAD. But I think I get what you mean. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that as a class library you've set the "Start external program" setting and the "Working directory".  That would in turn allow you to debug within the AutoCAD process space and kick AutoCAD off when you start automatically.  As for loading, you could add a LISP call to Netload the application on startup via your menu's Acad.lisp file.  The two together would allow you to auto-start AutoCAD and auto-load your application to debug and keep it a class library.  There may be other more creative ways along that line too.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this party, but in case it's still relevant..

I do this all the time. Bascially the process is:
Create the WPF Application Project
Change it's type to Library.
IMPORTANT, delete App.xaml and App.xaml.cs

Create a 2nd Project of type Application. This will be a 'Harness' to test your Library project. It's basically a simple window that hosts the WPF interface created in your Library project. It will also typically create and inject some dummy data, just for debugging and testing.

The Harness application is set to Startup, so you can debut without having to fire up AutoCAD (which yes, makes for a long cycle). However, for release simply do not output the Harness project.

HTH